# An inequality for a maximal function on an $n$-ball.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

We have $Mf(x) = \sup_{r>0} \frac{c_n}{r^n} \int_{|y|\le r} |f(x-y)| dy$ the maximal function, where $r^n/c_n$ is the volume of the n-dimensional ball of radius $r$, $|y|\le r$.

I want to show that for $f_j=\chi_{(2^{j-1},2^j)}$, where $\chi$ is the charactersitic function, and $j=1,2,3,\ldots$, that: $Mf_j(x) \geq 1/8$ if $|x|\le 2^j$.

Here's, what I have done:
$2^{j-1} \le |x-y| \le 2^j$, so we get that $|y|<2^{j+1}$ and $|y|\le r$.

So we have that $Mf_j(x) \ge c_n/r^n \cdot r^n/(c_n\cdot 2^{(j+1)n})$ 
I don't see how to get the eighth there, anyone can help me with this?

It appears in Stein's real variable methods, orthogonality, and oscillatory integrals, 1993 edition pages 50-51.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This estimate is a consequence of the explicit computation of the maximal function of a nonempty open interval $(a,b)$. By considering cases on $x$ and $r$, it is not hard to verify the following result.

> **Lemma** For $-\infty\leq a<b\leq\infty$,
>   $$M\chi_{(a,b)}(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & {a<x<b}\\ \\
> 2^{-1}\dfrac{b-a}{x-a} & {x\geq b}\\ \\ 2^{-1}\dfrac{b-a}{b-x} & 
> {x\leq a}\end{cases}$$

*Proof:* Fix $-\infty\leq a<b\leq\infty$. Let $\mathcal{A}_{r}(x)$ denote the symmetric average at $x$ of radius $r>0$. We consider three cases for $x$: $a<x<b$, $x\leq a$ and $x\geq b$.

1. Suppose $a<x<b$. Observe $\left|x-y\right|<r$ and $a<y<b$ imply that
   $$\mathcal{A}_{r}(x)=\dfrac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r}\chi_{(a,b)}(y)dy=\dfrac{\min\left\{x+r,b\right\}-\max\left\{x-r,a\right\}}{2r}$$
   If $r\leq\min\left\{\left|x-a\right|,\left|x-b\right|\right\}$, $\mathcal{A}_{r}(x)=1$. If $\left|x-a\right|\geq r>\left|b-x\right|$, then
   $$\mathcal{A}_{r}(x)=\dfrac{b-(x-r)}{2r}=\underbrace{\dfrac{b-x}{2r}}_{<1/2}+\dfrac{1}{2}<1$$
   The argument for $\left|x-b\right|\geq r>\left|x-a\right|$ is completely analogous, and if $r>\max\left\{\left|b-x\right|,\left|a-x\right|\right\}$, then
   $$\mathcal{A}_{r}(x)=\dfrac{b-a}{2r}<\dfrac{b-a}{\left|x-b\right|+\left|x-a\right|}=1$$
   We conclude that $M\chi_{a,b}(x)=1$, if $a<x<b$.
2. Now suppose $x\geq b$. If $r\leq\left|x-b\right|$, then $\mathcal{A}_{r}(x)=0$. If $r>\left|x-b\right|$, then
   $$\mathcal{A}_{r}(x)=\dfrac{b-\max\left\{x-r,a\right\}}{2r}$$
   If $r\leq\left|a-x\right|$, then
   $$\mathcal{A}_{r}(x)=\dfrac{b-(x-r)}{2r}=-\dfrac{\left|x-b\right|}{2r}+\dfrac{1}{2},$$
   which is maximal when $r=\left|x-a\right|$. As $\mathcal{A}_{r}(x)$ is decreasing on $r\geq\left|x-a\right|$, we conclude that $M\chi_{(a,b)}(x)$ is as stated.
3. Lastly, suppose that $x\leq a$. If $r\leq\left|x-a\right|$, then $\mathcal{A}_{r}(x)=0$. If $r>\left|x-a\right|$, then
   $$\mathcal{A}_{r}(x)=\dfrac{\min\left\{x+r,b\right\}-a}{2r}$$
   If $r\leq\left|b-x\right|$, then
   $$\mathcal{A}_{r}(x)=\dfrac{(x+r)-a}{2r}=-\dfrac{\left|x-a\right|}{2r}+\dfrac{1}{2},$$
   which is maximal for $r=\left|x-b\right|$. As $\mathcal{A}_{r}(x)$ is decreasing on $r\geq\left|x-b\right|$, we conclude that $M\chi_{(a,b)}(x)$ is as stated.

$\Box$

Restricting now to the case $(a,b)=(2^{j-1},2^{j})$ and $\left|x\right|\leq 2^{j}$, we have that

$$Mf_{j}(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & {2^{j-1}<x<2^{j}}\\ \\ \dfrac{1}{2} & {x=2^{j}} \\ \\ 2^{-1}\dfrac{2^{j-1}}{2^{j}-x}\geq \dfrac{2^{j-2}}{2^{j}-(-2^{j})}=\dfrac{1}{8} & {-2^{j}\leq x\leq 2^{j-1}}\end{cases}$$

Comment: How do you get the first identity? I mean $\chi_{(a,b)}(x-y) =1$ whenever $a<x-y<b$ and otherwise it's zero. And we also have $|y|\le r$. I don't see how do you get those identities.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: Yes, but $r$ is allowed to vary. In particular, it can be taken sufficiently large so that $a<x-y<b$ for all $y$ in a set of positive measure. If $x\leq a$, take $r>\left|a-x\right|$; if $r\geq b$, take $r>\left|x-b\right|$.

Comment: How does the factor of $1/2$ appear there?, I see that for example in the case of $x\ge b$ you take $r>x-b$, so $a<x-y<b$ $-r<y<\min(x-a,r)$. So the integral yields: $\min((x-a+r),2r)$, but I don't see how do you get your result.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: The factor of $1/2$ comes from the fact that "volume" of the ball $B(0,r)$ for $n=1$ is $2r$. For the record, this is a standard exercise in Fourier Analysis. See Example 2.1.2 in L. Grafakos, Classical Fourier Analysis.

Comment: Grafakos doesn't explicity calculate this example, do you happen to know an explicit calculation of this example?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: No, not off the top of my head. I added more details for the computation of the example. I'm not sure how to provide a more useful answer.